# Hibernate transaction rollback issue

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using hibernate 4.0 and spring 3.0 for my web application.

It is not getting rollback when i have throw exception in BaseController.handle* method.
Here my advice sinppet for rollback of transaction.

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="handleRequest*" rollback-for="Throwable" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
    <aop:config  proxy-target-class="true">
        <aop:pointcut id="handleRequestOperation"
            expression="execution(* com.abc.BaseController.handle*(..))" />
    </aop:config>
```

Comment: Does your BaseController has the method handleRequest or just handle?

Comment: I never used xml configuration for transaction management. But it requires @transactional on method/class. Not sure it is required for xml based configuration.